# Java How to remove apostrophes from a string based on the preceding character

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove the apostrophes in a string based on the preceding character. Please let me know the most efficient way to do this. If apostrophe is found in a string and the preceding character is `{D, L, O, d, l, o}`, then I would like to keep the apostrophe. Any other letter, remove it.

few examples:

```
Name        |Expected outcome
F'redricks  |Fredricks
D'Angelo    |D'Angelo
O’Brien     |O'Brien
L'Beam      |L'Beam
d'Angelo    |d'Angelo
o’Brien     |o'Brien
l'Beam      |l'Beam
'''AAAA'''' |AAAA
'D'Angelo   |D'Angelo   
‘O’Brien    |O'Brien
‘L'Beam     |L'Beam
```

Comment: What happens with `Toys'R'Us`?

Comment: @JimGarrison Probably the same thing that happens with S'mores.

Comment: A hint: You cannot handle all the variations that occur in the real world using something as simple as a regex.  I worked for a publishing company for 7 years and had to handle mailing list standardization, and one of the hardest problems we had was exactly this.  We developed a huge lookup table of correct formatting of names, but even then never achieved better than 99% accuracy (which is not all that good when you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of records).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex replace with a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
input = input.replaceAll("(?i)(?<![dlo])'", "");
```

This removes any apostrophe not preceded by d, l or o. The `(?i)` flag is for case-insensitivity.